# How do I get vector feature data from an OpenStreetMap layer?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, openstreetmap, geojson, json

I imported the OSM tile layer and can see it visually. But how do I access the actual data of the layer? It's vector data, made of points, lines, and polygons, right? How can I access the feature data for some part of the map, like as json?

Ex: Get the data for the polylines/polygons making up the streets/blocks of a town.

Comment: tile = raster, you want to edit in leaflet?

Comment: @Mapperz I don't even need to edit (though it'd be nice!), I just want the vector data underlying the streets and blocks I see so that I can overlay shapes and move them along particular streets/blocks.

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/61668/how-to-get-feature-data-from-osm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly export the data from the osm website by zooming to the required area then clicking on the Export button at the top of the site
[image].

---

The data will be exported in .osm format then it can be manipulated and converted to other formats like geojson or shapefile with the use of QGIS. For this Under the Vector menu in QGIS Openstreetmap is to be clicked and on "Import Topology From XML"[image]

---

Then it will create a SpatiaLite DB file, then Export Topology to SpatiaLite is to be done. The data can be exported by selecting points/lines/polygons which will create spatialite layer will be loaded into the display. Then finally these data can be selected based on their attributes and exported to geojson data format using the "save as" option on right click of the layer.

Answer (score 4):

I use overpass-turbo.eu when I need quick vector data from OpenStreetMap. It has a "wizard" that allows for quick data extraction and converts it into useful formals for leaflet, such as geojson.

Answer (score 1):

Use the OSM API, see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API .

For read-only queries of some specific subsets of data (e.g. streets only), consider using the Overpass API (see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). For larger datasets, use a planet dump or a planet extract. In any case, I suggest you spend some time reading the documentation at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Develop.

Comment: **Don't** use the OSM API. This API is for for *editing* purposes only. Don't use it for queries. Use Overpass API instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JOSM tool. It can download vector data and export it to diff formats. You can download OSM base dumps in format, such as xml, pbf and shapefile.